# how to sort a string in array by recent add flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have get an index here but I want display it from first to last in image : *I want to display "hello" first then the rest*[image]

code:

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("groups")
                  .doc(groupId)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                var chats = snapshot.data?["chats"];
                return ...)};

               ListView.builder(
                              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                              itemCount: chats.length,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return  Text(chats[index]),
                                         
                              }),
```

Basically I want to display the recently added string first.

Comment: Just add reverse: true,   on your listview

reverse: true,

Comment: Simple but works!! Thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `reverse: ture` in your listView,
like this:

```
     ListView.builder(
     reverse:true,
                              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                              itemCount: chats.length,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return  Text(chats[index]),
                                         
                              }),
```